# MongoDB sort by "starts with"

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting

I have a list of data in Mongo that I need to sort based on a user's inputted value.

For example, I have the following data:

```
Los Angeles, CA
East Los Angeles, CA
West Los Angeles, CA
North Los Angeles, CA
South Los Angeles, CA
```

I want to return all results that match this, but have the ones that start with the result first. Currently my data returns like this when a user enters "Los Angeles, CA":

```
East Los Angeles, CA
Los Angeles, CA
North Los Angeles, CA
South Los Angeles, CA
West Los Angeles, CA
```

What I would like this is when a user enters "Los Angeles, CA":

```
Los Angeles, CA
East Los Angeles, CA
North Los Angeles, CA
South Los Angeles, CA
West Los Angeles, CA
```

Is it possible to sort based on a starts with?

Answer (score -1):

```
db.collection.find( { $query: {}, $orderby: { name : -1 } } )
```

the name means above string field name

Comment: This will only sort the data in the alphabetical order...